# Apply conditional validation on AngularJS Directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, templates, angularjs-directive

I want to apply conditional validation on directive template.
I have a below drop-down `TransportMode`:
[image]

When user select AIR then it display AIR directive template.
Like:[image]

And also another temlate for SEA directive.
Like:[image]

Here what i need, after selecting any of the value in drop-down and related template shown in view so user only able to press Save button when they are entered minimum single records in related template.
Like:[image]

This is my validation whatever template was shown in view, user must entered minimum 1 records in that template.

I am trying with below code:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.manifestCreateDto.airFreights', function (airFreightsData) {            
  vm.manifestform.$setValidity('vm.manifestCreateDto.airFreights', airFreightsData != null && airFreightsData.length > 0);
}, true);
$scope.$watch('vm.manifestCreateDto.seaFreights', function (seaFreightsData) {
  vm.manifestform.$setValidity('vm.manifestCreateDto.seaFreights', seaFreightsData != null && seaFreightsData.length > 0);
}, true);
```

Below code for displaying template in view:

```
<fieldset class="scheduler-border" ng-show="vm.manifestCreateDto.transportModeId == '1'">
  <legend class="scheduler-border">
  </legend>
  <div class="row" id="divFreight">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div ng-model="vm.manifestCreateDto.airFreights" add-air-freight data='vm.manifestCreateDto.airFreights' ng-required='vm.manifestCreateDto.transportModeId == "1"'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="scheduler-border" ng-show="vm.manifestCreateDto.transportModeId == '3'">
  <legend class="scheduler-border">
  </legend>
  <div class="row" id="divSeaFreight">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div ng-model="vm.manifestCreateDto.seaFreights" add-sea-freight data='vm.manifestCreateDto.seaFreights' ng-required='vm.manifestCreateDto.transportModeId == "3"'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Basically, you would like to Dinamically change directive's template based on dropdown click?

Comment: yes that was i already done but i need validation for selected template. User should be entered 1 record minimum. It means that template length was 1.